# Getting this error No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, jackson2

```
@Entity
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class SomeRandomEntity {
  private String var1;
  private String var2;
  private String var3;
  public JSONObject getJSONObject throws JSONException {
        JSONObject properties = new JSONObject();
        properties.put("var1", getVar1());
        properties.put("var2", getVar2());
        properties.put("var3", getVar3());
        return properties;
    }
}
```

This POJO object is being given to frontend in the form of json object. But while fetching the data in the frontend this error is appearing.

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.json.JSONObject]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl["content"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->com.artifact.group.SomRandomDTO["jsonobject"])] with root cause 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl["content"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->com.artifact.group.SomRandomDTO["jsonobject"])
```

The error goes away when I add @JsonIgnore in the getJSONObject. The getJSONObject method is being considered a getter method and jackson tries to serialize that too. I want to understand this behaviour of jackson and why @JsonIgnore is rectifying the error?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a DTO or an entity? Those are mutually exclusive concepts.

Comment: This is an entity. But I am little confused between DTO and entity. Can you please explain that too?

Comment: DTO stands for "data-transfer object" and _specifically_ means a data structure intended for use as a transfer model (such as mapping to JSON for HTTP or messaging). An entity is the actual business object, such as mapping a database record.

Answer (score 2):

Here your object when you return it in response is getting `Serialized` to json string using `ObjectMapper` which is used in spring's MessageConverter(i.e `Jackson2HttpMessageConverter`) bean. Now the error is caused due to how `ObjectMapper` serializes your class. Your class has 4 filed, 3 of type `String` and 1 of type `JSONObject`. `ObjectMapper` when serializing fields, tries to find the corresponding serializer based on the field type. There are some out-of-the-box implementation of serializer for known type like `String` but for your custom type you either need to provide serializer to `ObjectMapper` bean via configuration of set property `SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS` to `false`.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
```

To verify this you can change the return type of method `getJSONObject` to `String` (as shown below) and your code will work.

```
public String getJSONObject throws JSONException {
        JSONObject properties = new JSONObject();
        properties.put("var1", getVar1());
        properties.put("var2", getVar2());
        properties.put("var3", getVar3());
        return properties.toString();
    }
```